# How to obtain Firebase/Google Cloud Storage Storage Download Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I understand that much of Firebase's services are wrappers around the Google Cloud platform (functions, storage etc..) I would like to obtain analytics on Google Cloud Storage downloads on an object basis (downloads, time). In the firebase console, it shows the amount of requests as well as the amount of data downloaded, but I don't know which objects were downloaded and how often. 
Is there a logging method or API in Google Cloud I can utilize to obtain this data?

Comment: You have the [Access Logs & Storage Logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) that allows you to get the information for all the requests made to a bucket. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [Access Logs & Storage Logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) that allows you to get the information for all the requests made to a bucket.

You will have to set up a bucket dedicated to store Access and Storage logs and then set logging for each bucket pointing to the dedicated one.